# Any word on when the YouTube API for Android is going to be released?

Tags: android, youtube-api

http://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/4479-youtube-android-player-api.html
there are a bunch of articles like the one above from the G i/o conference.  But since then... radio silence.  Does anyone have any insight on when this API is going into production?

All relevant news/links greatly appreciated.

Comment: The time has come: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's been no official dates yet, but I can tell you the teams been working very hard and we hope to launch it soon.

UPDATE:

API is released (Experimental version):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: fantastic! is there a place where this will be announced that I can keep an eye on, or is this just going to be a general Press release like the previous ones?

Comment: Is it going to be available only for ICS and higher versions ? :\

Comment: It will be available for Froyo 2.2 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when it is going to be released but they have some code in their open source google i/o application.

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Here for example:

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/#git%2Fandroid%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fyoutube%2Fapi%253Fstate%253Dclosed

And the activity that is supposed to use it:

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/SessionLivestreamActivity.java